# overload operator=, different class as argument

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a problem with below code, it compiles, yet the output crashes to desktop without giving me any suggestion what i'm doing wrong.

I know the problem is within operator= overloading at 'Ciezarowy::operator = (const Samochod &sam)' and its executed at
    'ciezar[0] = samochody[0];'

Sorry for long main() but i'm doing it for learning purpose so i want to see result for all actions.

here's the code, compiled by CodeBlocks/MinGW.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


class Samochod{

public:

string marka;
int pojemnosc;
double przebieg;
Samochod();
Samochod operator = (const Samochod &sam);
Samochod(const Samochod &sam);
};

Samochod::Samochod()
{

string marki[5] = {"Opel","Audi","Toyota","Fiat","Mazda"};
int index = rand() % 5;
marka = marki[index];
pojemnosc = rand() % 2000 + 1200;
przebieg = 40000;
}


Samochod Samochod::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
{

marka = sam.marka;
pojemnosc = 3000;
przebieg = sam.przebieg;
}



Samochod::Samochod(const Samochod &sam)
{

marka = sam.marka;
pojemnosc = 3000;
przebieg = sam.przebieg;
}



class Osobowy:public Samochod
{
public:
Osobowy();
int lpas;
double pojb;
int ldrzwi;
};

Osobowy::Osobowy()
: lpas( 5 )
, pojb( rand() % 100 + 80 )
, ldrzwi ( 5 )
{

}

class Ciezarowy:public Samochod
{
public:
Ciezarowy();
int losi;
double ladownosc;
bool samow;
Ciezarowy operator = (const Samochod &sam);

};

Ciezarowy::Ciezarowy()
: losi ( rand() % 2 + 2 )
, ladownosc ( 1000 )
, samow ( 1 )
{

}


Ciezarowy Ciezarowy::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
{
    marka = sam.marka;
    przebieg = sam.przebieg;
}


int main()
{
srand( time( NULL ) );
Samochod samochody[4];

Samochod samoch[3];

for ( int i = 0;i<3;i++){
   samoch[i] = samochody[i];}

cout<<samochody[0].marka<<endl;
cout<<samochody[0].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samochody[0].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<samochody[1].marka<<endl;
cout<<samochody[1].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samochody[1].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<samochody[2].marka<<endl;
cout<<samochody[2].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samochody[2].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<samochody[3].marka<<endl;
cout<<samochody[3].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samochody[3].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<samoch[0].marka<<endl;
cout<<samoch[0].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samoch[0].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<samoch[1].marka<<endl;
cout<<samoch[1].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samoch[1].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<samoch[2].marka<<endl;
cout<<samoch[2].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<samoch[2].przebieg<<endl;

Osobowy osob[3];

osob[1].ldrzwi = 3;
osob[1].lpas = 4;
cout<<osob[0].marka<<endl;
cout<<osob[0].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<osob[0].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<osob[0].ldrzwi<<endl;
cout<<osob[0].lpas<<endl;
cout<<osob[0].pojb<<endl;
cout<<osob[1].marka<<endl;
cout<<osob[1].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<osob[1].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<osob[1].ldrzwi<<endl;
cout<<osob[1].lpas<<endl;
cout<<osob[1].pojb<<endl;
cout<<osob[2].marka<<endl;
cout<<osob[2].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<osob[2].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<osob[2].ldrzwi<<endl;
cout<<osob[2].lpas<<endl;
cout<<osob[2].pojb<<endl;

Ciezarowy ciezar[2];

ciezar[0] = samochody[0];

   ciezar[1].ladownosc = 500;
   ciezar[1].samow = 0;

cout<<ciezar[0].marka<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[0].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[0].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[0].losi<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[0].ladownosc<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[0].samow<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[1].marka<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[1].pojemnosc<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[1].przebieg<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[1].losi<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[1].ladownosc<<endl;
cout<<ciezar[1].samow<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator= should return a reference to the object. Right now it doesn't return anything. It is **Undefined Behavior** to flow out of a non void function without returning anything.

```
Samochod& Samochod::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
        ^^
{
    if(this == &sam)
        return *this;

    marka = sam.marka;
    pojemnosc = 3000;
    przebieg = sam.przebieg;
    return *this;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: But this should show a compiler error and wont quit i believe

Comment: It will show a warning. But not an error I think. Let me check.

Comment: @Named Just a warning. Missing returns is one of those really old C baggage features.

Comment: Actually it's a good hint, i used it to edit :

    `<code> Ciezarowy& Ciezarowy::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
    {
        marka = sam.marka;
        przebieg = sam.przebieg;
        return *this;
    } `
And it worked :)

Comment: @pmr The real motivation why it is undefined behavior is because the compiler cannot detect it in all of the cases.

Comment: @JamesKanze Interesting. I thought it was to allow code that knows in which register to place the return value.

Comment: @pmr If there's no return value, the compiler doesn't have to place it anywhere.  IIRC, in C, falling off the end is _not_ an error in this case; it's only an error to attempt to use the return value.  (In C++, the compiler must generate code to destruct the returned object at the call site, even if you don't use it.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `<string>`

Your assignment operators must return something or this is undefined behavoir

```
Samochod Samochod::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
{
    marka = sam.marka;
    pojemnosc = 3000;
    przebieg = sam.przebieg;
    return *this;
}
```

Its traditional to return a reference

```
Samochod& Samochod::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
{
    marka = sam.marka;
    pojemnosc = 3000;
    przebieg = sam.przebieg;
    return *this;
}
```

Its also pretty much imperative to check that this != &rhs when you're writing assignment operators. You can get away with it in limited cases but you'll eventually regret it.

```
Samochod& Samochod::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
{
    if(this != &sam)
    {
        marka = sam.marka;
        pojemnosc = 3000;
        przebieg = sam.przebieg;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

EDIT: Its well worth cranking the warning level up and treating warnings as errors. This is especially worth it in new C++ code bases where you don't need a lot of the legacy weirdness - its much easier to write warning free code than it is to convert an old code base to it. It would catch issues like this and a whole lot more.

Comment: The need to check for self assignment in an assignment operator is almost always an indication that the assignment operator is broken to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

change the return type as shown below

```
Samochod Samochod::operator = (const Samochod &sam)
{
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way i could think of is template template parameters. All, kindly point out if my understanding is incorrect.